# How to know index of a decimal value in a python list

Tags: python

I have a list like the following

```
['UIS', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '02/05/2014', 'N', '', '', '', '', '9:30:00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '31.8000', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3591', 'O', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0']
```

Now how to know which element is decimal here , basically I want to track the `31.8000` value from the list. Is it possible ?

Comment: You loop over it and find it. What do you mean by _track_?

Comment: yes but how to know is it a decimal or not , I cant use isinstance as `'31.8000'` is a string here

Comment: the built-in function `float` mentioned below can parse strings, and will throw a `ValueError` if it fails to parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reliably find if a variable has a floating point number or not, by literal evaluating and checking if it is of type `float`, like this

```
from ast import literal_eval
result = []
for item in data:
    temp = ""
    try:
        temp = literal_eval(item)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        pass
    if isinstance(temp, float):
        result.append(item)
print result
# ['31.8000']
```

If you want to get the indexes, just `enumerate` the data like this

```
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    ...
    ...
```

and while preparing the `result`, add the index instead of the actual element

```
        result.append(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list and check if `float()` succeeds:

```
floatables = []

for i,item in enumerate(data):
    try:
        float(item)
        floatables.append(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print floatables
```

Alternatively, if you want to match the decimal format you can use

```
import re
decimals = []

for i,item in enumerate(data):
    if re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", item) is not None:
        decimals.append(i)

print decimals
```

Comment: yes but `float` will convert elements like  `100` and `0` also to `float` .

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and a regular expression match:

```
>>> import re
>>> [float(i) for i in x if re.match(r'^[+-]\d+?[.]\d+$',i)]
[31.8]
```

If you want to tracking the indexes of the floats:

```
>>> [x.index(i) for i in x if re.match(r'[+-]?\d+?[.]\d+',i)]
[24]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['UIS', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '02/05/2014', 'N', '', '', '', '', '9:30:00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '31.8000', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3591', 'O', '', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0']

import decimal

target = decimal.Decimal('31.8000')

def is_target(input):
    try:
        return decimal.Decimal(input) == target
    except decimal.InvalidOperation, e:
        pass

output = filter( is_target, data)
print output
```